# how to keep apache flink task and submit record when restart jobmanager

Tags: apache-flink

I am using apache flink 1.10 to batch compute my stream data, today I move my apache flink kubernetes(v1.15.2) pod from machine 1 to machine 2 and find all submit task record and task list disappear, what's happening? the summit record is in the memory? what should I to keep my submit record and task list when restart the kubernetes pod of apache flink? I just found checkpoint persistant but nothing about tasks.

If lose the running task history, I must upload my task jar and recreate all task, so many task should to recreate if lose the history, is there any possible to resume the task automaticlly?

Comment: have you considered taking savepoints for each job? and then restoring them from these savepoints.

Comment: savepoint not save the task history,how to restore the running task or keep the task history in UI,and I am free to reimport all tasks.

Comment: If you are talking about the history server, I think you need to set the directories for storing history as mentioned here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/historyserver.html#configuration

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The configurations that might not be set are:

**Job Manager**

```
jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs
```

**History Server**

```
# Monitor the following directories for completed jobs
historyserver.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs

# Refresh every 10 seconds
historyserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval: 10000
```

Please look at for more details: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/historyserver.html#configuration